# AngularJS bootstrap class

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-class

I have the following angularjs ng-repeat ,column status have three values (Phoned,Active,Waiting)

```
 <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">                 
 <td>{{person.id}}</td>
 <td>{{person.status}}</td> 
</tr>
```

I need to apply bootstrap class depending on the value of status,like the following image

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ng-class` directive

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons">                 
   <td>{{person.id}}</td>
   <td ng-class="{'phoned':person.status === 'Phoned',
                  'active':person.status === 'Active',
                  'waiting':person.status === 'Waiting'}">
    {{person.status}}
   </td> 
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.phoned{
   background-color: blue;
}
.active{
   background-color: green;
}
.waiting{
   background-color: orange;
}
```